# gulp-postcss: набор опций (плагинов) в зависимости от условия

Tags: javascript, gulp, frontend, postcss

Я ознакомился со списоком так называемых оптимизаций `cssnano` ([list of cssnano optimizations](http://cssnano.co/guides/optimisations/)): он включает в себя `autoprefixer` (не по умолчанию), `cssnano-util-raw-cache` и другие плагины.

Далее, в [документации gulp-postcss](https://github.com/postcss/gulp-postcss) я увидел такой пример:

```
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    var plugins = [
        autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 1 version']}),
        cssnano()
    ];
    return gulp.src('./src/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});
```

Возникает путанца: непонятна иерархия между `postcss`, `cssnano` и `autoprefixer`. В примере выше `cssnano` и `autoprefixer` объявлены по отдельности и дальше они идут как плагины `postcss`. Это было бы терпимо, но из-за путаницы в иерархии непонятно, как использовать другие postcss-плагины (они же "оптимизации cssnano" согласно первой ссылке).

В примере ниже я хочу использовать плагин `postcss-calc` как в development-сборке, так и production-сборке, а минификатор `postcss-normalize-whitespace` - только в продакшен-сборке. Как мне следует дополнить приведённый ниже код, чтобы всё работало?

```
const   gulp = require('gulp'),
        gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
        sass = require('gulp-sass'),
        postcss = require('gulp-postcss')；

const isDevelopment = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'develpment';

gulp.task('styles', function(){

    // сначала указываем общий набор плагинов для обоих сборок
    let plugins = [
        autoprefixer({ browsers: ['>= 1%', 'last 5 major versions', 'ie >= 6']}),
        // ...
    ];

    if (isDevelopment) {
        plugins.push(/* плагины для development-сборки */);
    }
    else {
        plugins.push(/* плагины для production-сборки */);  
    }

    return gulp.src(HPath.sassSourceFilesSelection)
        .pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))

        // ...

});
```